# How can I reduce duplication across multiple Xcode targets?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an iOS app with multiple targets: Prod, Beta, Alpha. Each target has different icons, a different bundle ID, and different preprocessor macros.

Unfortunately, there's also a lot of duplication across the targets (URL schemes, build settings, etc.). It's a pain to have to make changes to this configuration in every target, and always worry that I missed a target.

Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: This is the same way I implement the same need. For settings other than preprocessor macros or images I usually create a separated custom configuration file for each target so it is easier edit when the settings grow.

Comment: It sounds like you're creating targets when you want to create configurations. Generally you don't have separate targets for production, beta, and alpha. You usually have a single target and select the configuration in your scheme to build and/or run the one you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was indeed doing it wrong.

I ended up merging targets and creating a Beta configuration, in addition to the existing Debug and Release configurations.